# Correct way to approach composite foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreign-keys, ef-code-first

I have multiple classes `X, Y, Z`:

```
public class X
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public class Y
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public class Z
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Each class has an `one-to-many` relation with the `Image` class.

I want to create a single column which can references to all those classes `X, Y, Z.`

Here's my `Image` class:

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int RefId { get; set; }
    public virtual X X { get; set; }
    public virtual Y Y { get; set; }
    public virtual Z Z { get; set; }
}
```

Is this a good way to minimize the number of foreign keys? Or is there some other approach I can try to make my fetch query faster?

Also what changes do I need to make in my fluent API?

Answer (score 0):

Same column for X,Y,Z won't work, since `RefId` is in `Image`. Consider this: an `Image` with `RefId = 1`, and X/Y/Z all have data with `Id = 1`, the `Image` won't know if it should be associated with X or Y or Z.

Besides, what if a new table `K` uses `Image`? You'd need to add new column for `K` in `Image` then, and every time a new table uses it.

Reconsider the requirements. Do you really need to access X/Y/Z from `Image`? For similar usecase, usually I only access `Image` through instances of X/Y/Z.

If you still want to keep the structure, a C#-only property might make things easier a little:

```cs
// ...
// Make X, Y, Z all inherit SomeInterface first
// ...

public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int RefId { get; set; }
    public virtual X X { get; set; }
    public virtual Y Y { get; set; }
    public virtual Z Z { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SomeInterface> Things => new [] {X,Y,Z}.Where(si => si != null).ToArray();
}
```

Still, I'd suggest rethink about the whole structure.

Answer (score 0):

In EF Core, you can use generic types to define tables. In a table-per-heirachy, child types can share the same database column and can define navigations.

So combining all of these facts together;

```cs
interface IHaveImages<T>
    where T : IHaveImages<T> {
    int Id { get; set; }
    List<Image<T>> Images { get; set; }
}
class X : IHaveImages<X> {
    int Id { get; set; }
    List<Image<X>> Images { get; set; }
}
abstract class Image {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Class { get; set; }
    int RefId { get; set; }
}
class Image<T> : Image
    where T : IHaveImages<T> {
    T Parent { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Image>(b => {
    b.HasDiscriminator(i => i.Class)
        .HasValue<Image<X>>("X");
});

modelBuilder.Entity<X>(b => {
    b.HasMany(x => x.Images)
        .WithOne(i => i.Parent)
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.RefId);
});
```

Though obviously, since the foreign keys share the same database column, you won't be able to create a real foreign key in the database.

If you wanted a database column per table so that you can create real foreign keys, you can map the `RefId` property in each child type to a unique column, without polluting your C# types with extra properties.